# Sending multiple keypresses WatiN

Tags: c#, watin, sendkeys

Ok so I am running tests in WatiN and I am using the SendKeys method. According to the MSDN website I can enter:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT 2}");
```

And this will enter left two times. This however does not work, I believe because the application needs time between each keypress. I order to do what I need the program to do I used Thread.Sleep between each keypress to ensure they were getting read. **Is there a more efficient/proper way to do this?** This is my current method code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}");
Thread.Sleep(500);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}");
Thread.Sleep(500);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: I had a problem with this while trying to debug.  What I *think* was happening is sendkey sends to the active window.  And because I'd set a breakpoint the active window was changed to visual studio.

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597848/key-strokes-in-watin

Comment: Thanks, but my issue isn't that it won't work. The keypresses are reading, just I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) there are timing issues with SendKeys:

> The SendKeys class is susceptible to timing issues, which some
>   developers have had to work around. The updated implementation is
>   still susceptible to timing issues, but is slightly faster and may
>   require changes to the workarounds.
>
> The SendKeys class tries to use
>   the previous implementation first, and if that fails, uses the new
>   implementation.
>
> As a result, the SendKeys class may behave differently
>   on different operating systems. **Additionally, when the SendKeys class
>   uses the new implementation, the SendWait method will not wait for
>   messages to be processed when they are sent to another process.** If
>   your application relies on consistent behavior regardless of the
>   operating system, you can force the SendKeys class to use the new
>   implementation by adding the following application setting to your
>   app.config file.

```
<appSettings> 
  <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/> 
</appSettings>
```

> To force the SendKeys class to use the previous implementation, use the value "JournalHook" instead.

You could try changing between implementations to see if there is a change in your results.

Alternately, according to this [post](http://community.opennetcf.com/forums/p/11219/66659.aspx#66659) just using `Thread.Sleep(0);` after your input should work.  Not the most elegant solution but if it works it would be faster than a 500ms pause.

Comment: I don't know, Sleep(0) isn't working for me. They still don't read. However, I looks like there really isn't a better way to do this.