# WatiN and breaklines

Tags: c#, watin

I want to enter value into text field with break lines to check some functionality of application. Like this:

```
value1
value2
```

I used Environment.NewLine, "\r\n" but WatiN translates them into spaces:

```
MyField.Value=("value1"+Environment.NewLine+"value2");
MyField.Value=("value1"+"\r\n"+"value2");
```

Manually all is OK. Is there a way to really imitate entering a break line in WatiN?

Comment: have you seen this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856766/can-i-pass-a-key-stroke-i-e-enter-key-into-application-using-watin-scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856766/can-i-pass-a-key-stroke-i-e-enter-key-into-application-using-watin-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions worked for me in a textarea set to more than 1 row:

```
textArea.SetAttributeValue("value", "abc" + Environment.NewLine + "123");

textArea.TypeText("abc" + Environment.NewLine + "123");
```

Make sure you set your Field to support multiple lines.